# Active Resource encoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I have a service which returns  ' 6"_x_5" ' as part of its json response, but active resource interprets this as ' 6���_x_4��� '. 
 When i curl against the same url the response looks fine, any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this is an encoding issue. what encoding is the app set to use? you may need to encode the value or escape them.

e.g.

```
'6\"_x_5\"'
```